# power meter ACPI000D:00: Ignoring unsafe software power cap and lost video signal

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a server with RAID 5 (2 Virtual Drive 500GB and 5.5 TB).

All the install was good but when i started Ubuntu i lost the video signal just afer this message : power meter ACPI000D:00: Ignoring unsafe software power cap
[image: Screenshot of boot before signal loss]

Why am I loosing the video signal?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is setting a graphical mode that the console cannot show.

Try adding this line in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX='text'
```

run `update-grub` and reboot

You should now have a login prompt